# Links don't work in Razor

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this code :

```
<a href="tel:0@Model.Work.Phone">0@Model.Work.Phone</a>
```

When I use phone like `0@Model.Work.Phone`, the `@` sign is not highlighted. And this looks like this in browser : 0@Model.Work.Phone . I mean the code is displayed instead of the phone number.

When I put a space like this :

```
<a href="tel:0 @Model.Work.Phone">0 @Model.Work.Phone</a>
```

The @ sign is higlighted but I want `0` and `@` to be next to each other. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I expect an [explicit expression](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) could work: `0@(Model.Work.Phone)`

Comment: @rene Would the parantheses be shown in browser? Thanks.

Comment: I have no box available to try it but based on what I recall they don't show up.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver This didn't work..

Comment: @rene I tried your code, the parantheses are shown.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver, it worked, thanks.

Comment: @jason that is strange because I just tried it and it works for me ... which version of Razor are you using? I'm using 2.0.x.  Phone is an int or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Razor (at least on 2.0 or up) you can use an [explicit expression](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/):

```
<a href="tel:0@(Model.Work.Phone)">0@(Model.Work.Phone)</a>
```

As an alternative you can use the direct string.format call as offered by [Gypsy Spellweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267324/links-dont-work-in-razor#comment71692876_42267324)

Another alternative is using an Razor delegate:

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> phoneformat = (item) =>
        {
            // if we have a string
            if (item is String && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                // check if the first is not a 0
                if (item[0] != '0')
                {
                    // add it
                    item = String.Format("0{0}", item);
                } 
            }
            else if(item is Int32)
            {
                /// ints never have leading 0, so add it
                item = String.Format("0{0}", item);
            }
            return item;
        };
}

<a href="tel:0@(Model.Work.Phone)">0@(Model.Work.Phone)</a> <br/>
<a href="tel:0@(Model.Work.PhoneInt)">0@(Model.Work.PhoneInt)</a>

<a href="tel:@phoneformat(Model.Work.Phone)">@phoneformat(Model.Work.Phone)</a> <br/>
<a href="tel:@phoneformat(Model.Work.PhoneInt)">@phoneformat(Model.Work.PhoneInt)</a>
```

Here is the Model I used:

```
public class Work
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int PhoneInt { get; set; }
}
```

And the Controller that fills it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.Work = new Work {Phone = "612345678", PhoneInt = 612345678};
    return View(model);
}
```

The rendered html content looks like this:

> ```
> <a href="tel:0612345678">0612345678</a> <br/>
> <a href="tel:0612345678">0612345678</a>
>
> <a href="tel:0612345678">0612345678</a> <br/>
> <a href="tel:0612345678">0612345678</a>
> ```